# @PathVariable The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect only when using Map

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, path-variables

I'm going through a Spring MVC tutorial and I'm trying to get the @PathVariable annotation to work.

When I explicitly name the path variables my code runs fine:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{first}/{last}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView doSomething(@PathVariable("first") String first, @PathVariable("last") String last) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("home");      
    model.addObject("message","HI " + first + " " + last);
    return model;
}
```

However when I try to use a map for the PathVariable I get an error 400: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{first}/{last}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView doSomething(@PathVariable Map<String,String> pathVars) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("home");
    String first = pathVars.get("first");
    String last = pathVars.get("last");
    model.addObject("message","HI " + first + " " + last);
    return model;
}
```

Both times I'm hitting the exact same URL and I'd expect the same behaviour from both of them.

I understand that in order to get this to work I have to add `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` to my context xml. But that doesn't seem to be making a difference.

This is what my servlet-context.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.mydomain.springmvctest" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>


    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Remove the redundant `annotation-driven`, if you haven't already.

Comment: If you turn your logs to DEBUG, Spring will tell you why it fails.

Comment: It says "Missing URI template variable 'pathVars' for method parameter type [java.util.Map]" Which is because I've not named it. I was under the impression you didn't have to if you put a map in there?

Comment: Looks like I might have been using an old version of Spring. I changed Maven to use 4.0.0.RELEASE  from 3.1.1.RELEASE and it works.

Comment: I feel like it should work for 3 as well. Eh, glad it works now.

Comment: Might be a bug in that particular release?

Comment: No, you're right. It was added in 4.

Answer (score 0):

Having played around with this a little it looks like using a more recent version of Spring fixed the issue.

I was initially using 3.1.1.RELEASE which is what STS defaults to when you create a Spring MVC project. I changed the pom to 4.0.0.RELEASE and everything works fine.